# Google Connection Apis not fetching All of its contacts, few contacts are missing

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I am trying to fetch google contacts. Its not showing all contacts. Few contacts are missing

Comment: Could you please provide the code related to the API request?

Comment: This is the Api Request i am using
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?pageSize=2000&personFields=names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers&access_token=${token}

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. In my case, all contacts are retrieved. Is it possible that you have more contacts than the `pageSize` value (only a maximum of 1000 can be retrieved), so you have to retrieve the rest via page tokens? (please note that you set `pageSize` to 2000, which is invalid, so it might default to 100). If that's the case, I'd consider posting an answer explaining how to handle that.